# Non-contiguous Count

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following data:

```
    M    T    W    T    F    S    S    ...
Matt                    x     
Dave     x              x
Jim                x
```

Where the days of the week are listed along the top for the current year and sick days are indicated via a 'x'.

How can I get a count of Friday Sick Days for Matt ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More a superuser question I think. But in modern (2007+) excel,

Assuming the days of the week are on row 1, and Matt's records are on row 2

```
=COUNTIFS($B2:$AA2,"x",$B$1:$AA$1,"F")
```

In old fashioned (<2007) excel

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B2:$AA2="x"),--($B$1:$AA$1="F"))
```

Note I'm not specifically picking up Matt in these formulae, I'm relying on the fact that Matt is always on a specific row. Also I'm assuming the data only goes up to column AA - extend if necessary.

Comment: for completeness, here's an additional formula for dynamically referencing the name (i.e. not relying on a specific row) =COUNTIFS(INDEX($B$1:$AA$4,MATCH("Matt",A:A,0),),"x",$B$1:$AA$1,"F")

Comment: Perfect. I was looking at COUNTIFS but misunderstood.